# <wasm:stripped> printed when logging from the runtime

Tags: polkadot, pallet, consensus

I'm trying to debug in pallet-staking to figure out something about how validators/nominators join NPoS network.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/pallet/impls.rs#L437

Code:

`log!(info, "Staking: Try trigger new era: Election Result:{:?}", election_result);`

Result when running node:

`Staking: Try trigger new era: Election Result:[(, <wasm:stripped>), (, <wasm:stripped>)]`

Question: What does`<wasm:stripped>` mean? This is only wasm binary? Can we convert this wasm to native rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a type derives `RuntimeDebug` instead of `Debug`, then this string literal is printed ONLY in wasm. You have two options here:

1. Run native via `--execution Native`.
2. Change the derive, and make sure the type derives `Debug`.

Comment: `SKIP_WASM_BUILD= cargo run -- --chain ...` . Does this? I also tested this but it's not working with run native.

Comment: edited my answer.

Comment: The reason for this, for those who are wondering, is because strings bloat the generated WebAssembly blob for the runtime and so it's better to leave them out.

Answer (score 2):

Today I learned there is a `force-debug` feature on crate `sp-debug-derive`, so if you add a dependency to that and enable that feature then you might well be able to see what you want to see.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/769bdd3ff33a291cbc70a800a3830638467e42a2/substrate/primitives/debug-derive/Cargo.toml#L31